# How to use my extracted triples in Apache Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena, triples

I have some extracted triples from some materials and I have compiled them into a clean graph. I want to use Apache Jena TDB to store my triples and Fuseki to do some queries. My question is that how I can convert my triples that recognized by Apache.

I read some material about RDF data, but I could not get the information I need. Do I have to convert my triples into RDF format to use Apache? The things that my graph describes are not very common, and some of the words cannot be found in existing RDF vocabulary. Please give me some instruction or relevant materials. I really do not know where to start.

Comment: you should read a tutorial about RDF or at least the RDF primer. Then you should know that RDF triple are made of subject, predicate, and object which itself are usually represented by URIs and/or literals. Afterwards, you should follow the instructions on the Jena docs.

Comment: Ah, and don't forget to read a SPARQL tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll do it!